# Alphabetic Style Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

When I used

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

I get references as [Yat+98] when number of authors is more than three. Is there a way to remove this plus sign?

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}`

Comment: See also [Biblatex - style = alphabetic - change plus sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130030/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
```