# Biblatex 'alphabetic' style '+' sign in citation key?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I noticed a strange citation key in my document. All citation keys with multiple authors are generated like this for example: `[Ber+07]`
Where does this `+` sign come from? I setup biblatex like so:

```
\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   maxcitenames=3,
   maxbibnames=3,
   style=alphabetic,
   sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}
```

Do I have to write my own biblatex style?

Comment: `maxcitenames=3` has little effect with `style=alphabetic,` and is the default value anyway. `maxbibnames=3` is also the default. (Indeed `maxnames=3` is the default setting, which sets both of the mentioned values to 3.) `sorting=nyt` is unusual together with `style=alphabetic`, the standard for `alphabetic` is `sorting=anyt`, which sorts by label first.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130030/35864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "+" is just a signal that the list of authors/editors has been truncated to fit into `maxalphanames` (the default value is 3), it works just like "et al." (and `maxcitenames`) in other styles.

> Uthor et al. 2006; Uthor and Riter 2006

would be

> Uth+06; UR06

The exact symbol is controlled with `\labelalphaothers`, so you could say

```
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{\&al}
```

to get

> Uth&al06

instead.

You can increase `maxalphanames` to a higher value if you don't want your list truncated.