# Remove the + for multiple authors in alpabetic cite style (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I am pretty new to LaTeX. I tried my best, but could not solve the problem myself.

By request of my thesis supervisor, I should use the `alpabetic` citestyle. If there is only one author, it works how I (and my supervisor) would like to have it, citations look like this:

> [Aut20]

But if there are multiple authors, citations look like this:

> [Aut+20]

Can anyone advise me how to get rid of the "+" for works with multiple authors?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A standard way is to use `et al.` which is provided by `biblatex`. it is not smart idea invent new way to designate more authors. Anyway, to receive help, please provide complete small document which demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '+' is inserted as an "et al." marker. It is controlled by `\labelalphaothers`, so if you want the marker gone and don't want to change anything else about the labels, just define

```
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,nussbaum,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Aks06; Nus78; SR98]]

Comment: This is one of the questions you think should have a duplicate, but I only found the near duplicates https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407015/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130030/35864, which don't quite make clear that it is OK and safe to make `\labelalphaothers` empty.